# How to catch the end filename only from a path with javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

If I have a variable 'path' which contains a full path with directories and all, to the filename, how can I strip everything except the filename?

ex:
Convert `dir/picture/images/help/filename.jpg` into `filename.jpg`

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A regular expression replace would work, barring any special function to do this:

```
var filename = path.replace(/.*\//, '');
```

Answer (score 2):

Whatever you use, consider whether the string may have a GET string or a hash tail,
and if a file name may not have an extension.

```
String.prototype.filename= function(){
   var s= this.substring(this.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
   var f=  /^(([^\.\?#]+)(\.\w+)?)/.exec(s);
   return f[1] || '';
}
var url= 'http://www.localhost.com/library/paul_1.html?addSrc=5';
alert(url.filename()) /*  returns>> paul_1.html */
```