# Remove sections of url to only keep file name

Tags: javascript, string, url, replace, lowercase

I want to remove everything in the URL and only keep the name of the file/image. The URL is a dynamic input/variable.

Code:

```
var str = "http://website.com/sudir/sudir/subdir/Image_01.jpg";
str = str.replace("http://website.com/sudir/sudir/subdir/", "")
         .replace(/[^a-z\s]/gi, '&nbsp;').replace("_", "&nbsp;")
         .replace("subdir", "").toLowerCase().slice(0,-4);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this easily with `lastIndexOf()`:

```
var str = "http://website.com/sudir/sudir/subdir/Image_01.jpg";
str.substring(str.lastIndexOf("/") + 1)
//"Image_01.jpg"
```

Answer (score 1):

This function will give you the file name,

```
function GetFilename(url)
{
   if (url)
   {
      var m = url.toString().match(/.*\/(.+?)\./);
      if (m && m.length > 1)
      {
         return m[1];
      }
   }
   return "";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From [How to catch the end filename only from a path with javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1799442/how-to-catch-the-end-filename-only-from-a-path-with-javascript)

```
var filename = path.replace(/.*\//, '');
```

From [Getting just the filename from a path with Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2526061/getting-just-the-filename-from-a-path-with-javascript?rq=1)

```
var fileNameIndex = yourstring.lastIndexOf("/") + 1;
var filename = yourstring.substr(fileNameIndex);
```

Answer (score 0):

I know you haven't specified the exact URL format and whether this may be possible in your situation, but this may be a solution worth considering.

Javascript

```
var str = "http://website.com/sudir/sudir/subdir/Image_01.jpg?x=y#abc";
console.log(str.split(/[?#]/)[0].split("/").slice(-1)[0]);

str = "http://website.com/sudir/sudir/subdir/Image_01.jpg";
console.log(str.split(/[?#]/)[0].split("/").slice(-1)[0]);
```

On [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/fdVdD/)

Answer (score 0):

You can always Regex to extract data from strings:
The Regex to extract data from URL:

```
"http://website.com/sudir/sudir/subdir/(?<FileName>[0-9A-Za-z._]+)"
```